# How do I show the values of deeply nested fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I have a tables of Users, Carts, Orders and OrderTransactions.

My schema looks like:

- User has one cart
- Cart has one order
- Order has many transactions

I would like to display the user_id in the order transaction partial.

I can display the cart_id with `<%= order_transaction.order.cart_id %>`

So I thought that `<%= order_transaction.order.cart.user_id %>` would work but it's giving a   "undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass" error.

What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: since you have an answer on your own, there is a comment about architecture design: the long chain breaks [Law_of_Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) principle, you can try to use **delegate** method in your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed, It does actually work. I needed to delete all transactions created before the changes I made.